# How are there so many Amolekites in Shmuel Aleph Chapter 30?

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of, amalek

In Shmuel Aleph Chapter 15, the Novi tells us that Sho'ul and Shmuel wiped out all of the Amolekites (Sho'ul killed most of them and Shmuel finished them off). The Midrash (I can't remember where exactly) says that there was one survivor, King Agag's wife, who was pregnant and gave birth to Vayezoso (we know his name from Targum Sheini on Esteir) who went on to rebuild Amolek.

Another Midrash I remember learning (once again I can't remember where) says that Sho'ul was only king of Israel for two years.

If we say that Vayezoso was born in the first year of Sho'ul's reign, and the Amolekites attacked Dovid's camp in Tziklog (Shmuel Aleph Chapter 30) at the end of the second year, this makes the only Amolekite male maximum 2-years-old, and the only other Amolekite, his mother.

How, then could lots of Amolekites attack Dovid's camp?

Comment: Good question. Why assume that all the Amelekites lived in one central area, though? I know that in Shmuel, it appears that they did, from a read of the story, but, maybe they were in other areas that Sha'ul didn't get to. Is it also possible that some escaped?